# Choosing open source application platform

Tags: open-source, api

At the current moment I've been working on assignment to select open source application platform for the company needs. Here are requirements to it:

- It should deploy, scale and balance applications via cluster;
- Handle, control and monitor low lever API calls and messages transfer via it (http requests, calls to DB, cache, etc);
- Handle jar's stability via some API\monitoring and providing recovery option to the applications;
- Should be easy to continue development of the platform as well as applications;
- Could provide suitable API for the developers.

So I've been researching this topic a bit and faced with 3 approaches that currently exists:

- Vertx (with Vertigo)
- AppScale
- Deis

App scale doesn't seems very promising from my perspective as it uses Google code that we can't modify in case and supports only Java, Python and Go.

Vertx and Deis looks very promising, so I would love to hear from you props and coins of each platform for the described needs.

Comment: Hello and welcome to swrec.SE! Please be a bit more specific when asking, both in text and tags. I can _guess_ you want a Java™ platform… but this is still a bit vague.

Comment: @mirabilos it could be Java platform but it is not required. It should be open source platform for sure and by the end of the day it has to be be deployed via Docker to OpenStack.

Comment: Please do not put the clarifications into the comments. Rather [edit] your question, then *maybe* write a comment stating so (so the one asking for clarification gets pinged) and delete that after a few days, to remove the clutter. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I can provide some information about AppScale.

[AppScale is a fully **open-source PaaS**](http://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki) based off of the Google App Engine model, meaning that the code is yours to modify. In the wiki you can find a list of technologies used to replicate GAE behavior.

It can host Python, Java, Go and PHP applications and can run on one or more Ubuntu VMs in a **distributed setup**. In the wiki (linked above) you can find a list of the supported Infrastructures on which AppScale can run, for example Amazon EC2, OpenStack and Microsoft Azure.

Also, unlike Google App Engine you can use any library or tool you want because there is **no sandbox limiting**, thus making it highly customizable.

AppScale deployments come with **auto-scaling** while still providing you with the freedom to modify your setup at any point. As for **balancing** and **control**, it relies upon tools such as HAProxy and Monit that give you a solid base for monitoring the system.

Finally, there is already an open-source backup and restore tool, and the AppScale Engineering Team, myself included, is currently working on a new and improved **backup and recovery suite** for the application and its data.

That said, I think you first and foremost need to figure out if the [GAE APIs](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/) are suitable for your company's needs.

Comment: sure GAE API suitable for the company needs but as I understand it owns by Google and I can't get access to the code to modify it. Let's say I need to change platform behavior in the following class com.google.appengine.api.channel.ChannelMessage and there is no chance to do this. Am I right ?

Comment: You can do this because AppScale is the free and open-source implementation of Google App Engine and here are the GitHub repositories with all the code: [AppScale](http://github.com/AppScale/appscale), [AppScale Tools](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale-tools). You are welcome to give it a try and if you have any questions we're always happy to answer them.

Comment: sure I installed this platform and tried it. However when I was looking for the ChannelMessage implementation there is no files like this...

Comment: so Appscale is bad because NO OPEN SOURCE for the platform API

Comment: Well the original code was not open so we decompiled and  modified it and [here](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/tree/master/AppServer_Java/src/com/google/appengine) are the source files. Also, [this](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjava%253Fstate%253Dclosed) is the source of the newest Java SDK version that Google released. Hope you find a platform that better matches your criteria.